# How to validate values of an multi dimensional hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap

I have an multidimensional hash like this

```
%hash = {'5' => {'DS' => 'TESTD1',
                 'DN' => 'TESTD1',
                 'PP' => 'APPLE44'},
         '6'=> {'DS' => 'TESTD2',
                'DN' => 'TESTD2',
                'PP' => 'APPLE44'},
         '7'=>{'DS' => 'TESTD1',
               'DN' => 'TESTD3',
               'PP' => 'APPLE44'} 
         '8'=>{'DS' => 'TESTD1',
               'DN' => 'TESTD1',
               'PP' => 'ORANGE33' }
          };
```

Now I want to check whether there are unique mappings between 'PP' values and 'DS' values for an entire hash .
For example 7th key isn't unique since it is same as 5th for DS and PP values.
only when both PP and DS values are same,I should increase the count.

So far i have tried using 'exists' but doesn't seem to work in the way I wanted to,So how do we accomplish this?

Comment: @xxfelixxx I am sorry,but a little code would make things clearer for me

Comment: ok, have some code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably ran into issues using `exists` because you defined your hash incorrectly.  You do `%hash = { ... }` when you should create a hash with `%hash = ( ... )` or create a hash reference with `$hash = { ... }`.  Have a read of [perldoc perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for all the gory details.

Use another hash to store the various DS / PP combinations and use that to check for uniqueness.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $hash = {
    '5' => {'DS' => 'TESTD1',
            'DN' => 'TESTD1',
            'PP' => 'APPLE44'},
    '6' => {'DS' => 'TESTD2',
            'DN' => 'TESTD2',
            'PP' => 'APPLE44'},
    '7' => {'DS' => 'TESTD1',
            'DN' => 'TESTD3',
            'PP' => 'APPLE44'}, 
    '8' => {'DS' => 'TESTD1',
            'DN' => 'TESTD1',
            'PP' => 'ORANGE33'},
};

my %check_for_dups;
for my $key ( sort keys %$hash ) {
    my $subhash = $hash->{ $key };
    my $combo = join '_', 'DS', $subhash->{ DS }, 'PP', $subhash->{ PP };
    $check_for_dups{ $combo }->{ $key } = 1;
}

my $found_dups = 0;
for my $combo ( sort keys %check_for_dups ) {
    my @keys_for_combo = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $check_for_dups{ $combo } };
    if ( scalar @keys_for_combo > 1 ) {
        print "Duplicate keys for combo '$combo' : " . join(',',@keys_for_combo) . "\n";
        $found_dups = 1;
    }
}

print "All combos are unique!\n"
    unless $found_dups;
```

**output**

```
Duplicate keys for combo 'DS_TESTD1_PP_APPLE44' : 5,7
```

Comment: I tried using count instead of dying when i found duplicates,but for some reason it's not working.it just doesn't come inside the 'if' loop

Comment: To keep track of the counts instead of dying on the first duplicate involves a bit more bookkeeping...but here you go.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
 my %dup; 
 if(exists($dup{'DS'}{'PP'}))
 {
     count++;
 }
```

Comment: This code doesn't answer your question. If you have a working solution you want to share, please do, but post the entire code.

Answer (score -1):

I am using kind of almost same as xxfelixxx answer, but in his code we can't find all the duplicates as script exists ( actually dies :) ) when it findsthe first duplicates.

Hence I have used hash of array to store the indexes of duplicates, so you know the indexes which are duplicates and count of them too ( count of array values )

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
my $hash = {'5' => {'DS' => 'TESTD1',
                 'DN' => 'TESTD1',
                 'PP' => 'APPLE44'},
         '6'=> {'DS' => 'TESTD2',
                'DN' => 'TESTD2',
                'PP' => 'APPLE44'},
         '7'=>{'DS' => 'TESTD1',
               'DN' => 'TESTD3',
               'PP' => 'APPLE44'},
         '8'=>{'DS' => 'TESTD1',
               'DN' => 'TESTD1',
               'PP' => 'ORANGE33' }
          };

my %result;
foreach (keys %{$hash}) {
   my $n_key = $hash->{$_}{'DS'} . '_' . $hash->{$_}{'PP'};
   if( ! defined $result{$n_key} ) {
      $result{$n_key} = [ $_ ];
   } else {
      push @{$result{$n_key}}, $_;
   }
}

foreach (keys %result) {
   if( @{$result{$_}} > 1 ) {
      my($DD, $PP) = split('_', $_);
      print "Duplicated values found for DD => $DD, PP => $PP, ";
      print "No of duplicates : ".scalar(@{$result{$_}})." and there respective indexes are @{$result{$_}}\n";
   }
}

print "$_ : @{$result{$_}}\n" foreach(keys %result);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Duplicated values found for DD => TESTD1, PP => APPLE44, No of duplicates : 2 and there respective indexes are 7 5
TESTD2_APPLE44 : 6
TESTD1_ORANGE33 : 8
TESTD1_APPLE44 : 7 5
```

Comment: I need to use count. Your answer would give mixed results

Comment: can you answer using count?

Comment: You should `use strict; use warnings 'all';`

Comment: @Dada, thanks for the valuable comments, Please find it added.

Comment: @Sherlock.H, No of duplicated indexes are already in the array and were printed, you should just made a count of array elements. Though I have added it now.